New baseboard heaters with central AC - thermostat wiring help
Apologies for the long post, I’m very new at this and wanted to provide as much detail as possible.
After renovations, I’m having an issue getting the baseboard heaters in the living room to work. Nearly everything is new, from the baseboard heaters themselves to the thermostats (except the AC unit in the mechanical room is not new).
I don’t know 100% for sure how things were set up and working before we acquired the condo. But, Air Conditioning is central with vents in each room, while heating is separate and is supplied via the baseboard heaters beneath each window in each room.
From the guide for new owners:
Q. How does the ventilation in the building work?
A. There are two complete ventilation systems: one on the even side, the other on the odd side. These ventilation units operate without a water tower and also provide central air conditioning. The thermostat on the wall of the main room of your unit allows you to adjust the heating level or cooling mode. The other button is the ventilation button.
The condo has a living room + 3 bedrooms. The central AC is working fine (although annoyingly loud, and unfortunately just next to the living room) and supplies air to each room. It’s controlled by the “main” thermostat in the living room. The baseboard heaters in the 3 bedrooms are each controlled by their own thermostat (one per room), and they also work fine.
The issue is with the baseboard heaters in the living room. There are 4 heaters, one under each window. They should all be connected and controlled together by the same thermostat. There were heaters there previously, but they were replaced with newer models as part of the teardown. The renovations were done by professionals but I lived remotely the entire time, so it’s difficult to know exactly who did what and how things used to be. There was a bit of a miscommunication about who should install the final thermostat in the living room, so it was eventually done separately by a HVAC company who didn’t have all the details after everything else was done and all the workers gone.
Behind the living room thermostat, there is a hole in the wall with 2 separate “jackets”. One of them contains 4 wires (Black/Red/Green/White), while the other has 2 wires (Black/White). My assumption is the 4 wires are for the central AC, while the 2 wires are for the heating.
Unlike in the 3 bedrooms which have a thermostat only for heating, the thermostat in the living room is a different brand/model altogether and is intended to control both the heating and the cooling. The HVAC company installed it how they thought it should work, but it seems to me they assumed the central unit would supply both cooling and heating, and they hooked it up according to the “single transformer” wiring diagram with a jumper cable (in blue) connecting R and Rh, and both black wires tied to the Common. I only found this out later after noticing that Heat mode is not working, and I removed the thermostat cover to investigate the situation. Heat mode would effectively also turn on the loud AC unit fan, but no hot or cold air would come out, and the baseboard heaters weren’t turning on.

Below are the thermostat details, and below that are the relevant pages from the instruction manual:
https://www.control4.com/solutions/products/thermostat/


I’m not at all an expert in this field, but my assumption is because heating is totally separate from cooling, this is a two transformer system (although I have 2 Black wires and not 2 Red wires, which is confusing). I rewired the thermostat by removing the blue jumper wire, moving the red wire (from what looks to be the AC “jacket”) from R to Rc, and moving the black wire from what I assume is the 2 wire “heater jacket” from C(ommon) to R, as follows:

Now, Cooling and Ventilation are (still) working as they should, although I also went into the setup menu and turned on the Fresh Air Ventilation option which was previously off. However, I ended up disabling the “Fresh Air Forces Fan” option since the AC unit is loud and I don’t want it on all the time when the system is just supposed to vent fresh air.

Question 1: Does my re-wiring of the AC/Heating look correct? After typing this all out, it struck me that maybe the black/white wires are for line-voltage baseboard heaters which wouldn’t work at all with this low-voltage thermostat… Although why are the 2 wires so thin implying they’re low voltage?
Question 2 (minor): Is turning on “Fresh Air Vent Installed” correct, given the description of the ventilation system in the building’s owner guide FAQ above?
Question 3 (minor): Does Fresh Air venting still do anything if I disabled forcing the fan on for ventilation?
Question 4: Most importantly, why does my Heat still not work? :) If I put the thermostat in Heat mode, I hear the “click” that turns it on, but just like before I did my rewiring, the AC system fan turns on although I get no Hot or Cold air out of it. The baseboard heaters still aren’t running either.
Question 5: I came across this setting below which I tried toggling to “Gas/Oil Heat (Equipment Controls Fan)”, which seems wrong given this is an electric heating system, but at least the loud AC fan doesn’t turn on when I change to Heat mode anymore. I still hear the relay “click” on the thermostat when the system is switching from Cool to Heat mode, the problem is the baseboard heaters still aren’t turning on.

Any recommendations on what else I can try to isolate the issue with the baseboard heaters would be greatly appreciated. As said, I know nothing about HVAC systems, but I can read wiring diagrams and am happy to test voltages etc. between any points if that helps. Pictures of everything (inside of baseboards, etc.) are here:
Additional Info

Do the baseboards come on when you short the black and white wires from the 2-wire cable to each other?

First, there is no 120 Volt AC  at the thermostat, it is all 24 Volt.

The AC and thermostat look typical. So the big question is whether the baseboard heaters can be controlled by low-voltage thermostats or only (as I suspect) directly by 120V or 240V thermostats, which are an entirely different beast. There are ways to merge the two, but it gets complicated.

Baseboard heaters run at mains voltage and often are controlled by a high-voltage thermostat but what you show here is a low-voltage thermostat. You'll need to go hunting to figure out whether there's some controller box that allows a low-voltage thermostat to operate the high-voltage baseboard heaters, then share information about what it is and how it's connected.

Do you have a neighbor with a working setup you could peek at? That might short-circuit the whole process, pun intended.

Thanks all for the replies. I think I agree that these are high-voltage baseboard heaters and this thermostat won't work. Does that imply that the thin black/white wires are not related to the heater and are for something else altogether (no idea what)? And I would have to find where the high voltage wires are... These are the heaters: https://www.ouellet.com/en-ca/products/opp.aspx and these are the heat-only thermostats in the other rooms which work https://www.sinopetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/Smart-Thermostat-Electric-Heating-Control4-TH1123ZB-C4-TH1124ZB-C4-Fact-Sheet-Sinope-A.pdf

First off, the color wire does not matter. The colors are for reference only to make things or industry standards easier to follow. So, that being said, industry standards are as follows: Yellow (cooling), White (Heat), Green (Indoor Fan), Red (24 Volt supply from transformer), Blue (Common side of transformer[like neutral is to 120 volts, blue is to 24 volts]).
Now, you have black wires-it looks like to C-common and to R-Heat as Rc is R-Cooling. Typically, if you had forced hot air, you would simply jump the Rc & R because a one transformer supply of 24 volts for both heat & cool.
It also looks like you have 2-blacks and 2-whites, a red and a green. This is uncommon but doesn't mean its wired wrong.
Also, what type of heat do you have? Electric baseboard? Forced Hot water baseboard (that would mean you have a boiler). If its electric, then you need a "line" or "high" voltage thermostat that would control the electric baseboard separately. If its a boiler system, sometimes you would have separate t-stats for heat and cool, sometimes just one t-stat depending on the system.
You need to have these answered before anyone can help you here.
Find out 1. Is it electric heat? 2. Is it forced hot water (you would have a boiler). This is where we need to start to answer and help you with your situation.

Thanks all for the comments. I was finally able to get the electrician back in and everything is resolved. To sum up, the thermostat wiring was correct (after I fixed it as explained in my orignal post), but the low voltage thermostat needed 2 Aube rc840t-240 relays to control the 4 line voltage baseboard heaters. The same thermostat also works to control an entirely separate AC system in cooling mode. I learned a lot while trying to troubleshoot and by reading all your responses.
